# How to use r.mapcalculator to change values within a raster cost map to negative

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis

I have created a cost map in r.cost module in GRASS (through QGIS). This is actually a distance map from a protected area and distance from protected area has been calculated in both directions. How I can change the values within protected area to negative? I think I should use r.mapcalculator module in GRASS.

Comment: I have created a mask layer of areas outside Protected area (let's say layer B) that I want them to have positive values, and what I need is to write a formula to add negative sign to values in layer A that are outside layer B.

Comment: I tried r.mapcalculator, multiplying A-B by -1. but, the new raster that is created is not layer A with negative and positive values, it is indeed layer A-B.

Answer (score 1):

This might do it:

```
r.mapcalc "distances_with_negatives = if(isnull(B), -1.0*A, A)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that I need a mask layer to cover the values that I do not want to be changed. So, I created a polygon of my "inverse" PA layer, and put it in r.mask as mask layer. Then, in r.mapcalculator, input the source layer and in equation just wrote -1*A. I did the same for my PA layer (as mask). Finally, I have two layers, one with positive and the other by negative values. I used r.null.to to change null to 0, and then in r.mapcalculator I added two layers (A+B). The resulting map, is exactly what I wanted: a raster cost map with negative values inside and positive values outside PA.